# File.new command for Ruby to upload mp3 file to soundcloud

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

I'm now trying to upload a mp3 file to Soundcloud. Here I'm bogged down to the use of File.new command in Ruby. 
I send a request and a passing parameter looks like the below.

```
Parameters: {..."mp3_1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff24d5e3ea8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/kk/y_wprlln2qv6mzylj03g14x00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160316-21426-14vu8x1.mp3>, @original_filename="datasecurity.mp3", @content_type="audio/mp3", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mp3_1\"; filename=\"datasecurity.mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n">}
```

Then, I write File.new command with the potentail file name and params[:mp3_1] like the below.

```
client = Soundcloud.new(:access_token => 'XXX')

track = client.post('/tracks', :track => {
  :title => 'This is my sound',
  :asset_data => File.new("file name",params[:mp3_1])
})
```

Now I get an error saying:
*no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String*

The paperclip function works ( storing file to the storage directly has been what I've done ) but this file.new doesn't allow me to move forward. If I can get any help, I really appreciate that (:

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already have a file, no need to create a new one with `File.new`

have a closer look to your dump :

```
 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/...../RackMultipart20160316-21426-14vu8x1.mp3
```

this is a file, you may use it directly in your call

```
client.post('/tracks', :track => {
         :title => 'This is my sound',
         :asset_data => params[:mp3_1].tempfile)
 })
```

Comment: Wow it is now working!! (: Thanks so much for your answer!! I just took as an answer!